# Zend Session DB Handler and Serialized Data

Tags: php, zend-framework, session, serialization

We are using Zend Framework 1.7 on a project (old, I know) and just made a change to move the session data from files to the database. This appears to be working fine in both environments we deployed it in.

However, there is one big difference: in environment A (PHP 5.2), the session data is being stored in a plaintext serialized format, e.g.:

```
key|[php serialized array]
```

In environment B (PHP 5.3), the data appears to be getting base64 encoded somehow:

```
IpgJ4fbSZ0v2qi4RmGcgQ9tP7YEUyN1R9-7oroGl4071fnlk_UVkkrkUcpdHdw_UsRYy-6NpL61gTuL2Htcmv3HU5UM3ClwSDndY40kyimDPs3SdS7gNHwhwdpailLOfrIxqV48hZDhNHKlIpSX2QZm0jOHjRhZc2kjXnMgqioLqJiDdgyUCRnqKcZ_ZtBISq8BAZARW61P5Ls_ZSO506ltuNqIJIJGkV2R7qvDKLLCtxUQUwd7P8IlJiC7iq_Q4GIn3gMr0KwAHLP6adzxSusVk5begrx9lBk9Dxp8KkJ8Gx8rfKJfvVBIJKZgmsFsWq41dV0J4y1Lgihvx9nU73g..
```

Both environments appear to be working otherwise, but I need to make sure we understand why this is happening, and I can't seem to find any documentation or similar situation anywhere. My assumption is that the difference in PHP version and/or configuration in php.ini is influencing it, but I am at a loss as to how.

Comment: What is the serialize handler set to in php.ini? Mine is `session.serialize_handler = php`

Comment: Yea, I should have mentioned, I did look at that -- both environments have it set just as yours (which should be the default for the Debian distribution of php).

Comment: compared the "session.hash_function" param in php.ini?

Comment: Yea, both configurations use `session.hash_function = 0` which should correspond to MD5, but as far as I know that is just for determining the session ID hash, not the actual session data. My impression is still that the session data is controlled somehow by the Zend Framework but I haven't been able to find it in the code. I just need to do a better code trace I suppose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem today on a clustered server, in one I had php 5.2 and in the other php 5.3.

My initial guess was also a version problem, but I found so far that suhosin was the problem since was encrypting the session.

You can decrypt the session, just in the machine it was encrypted; to do you you should change the following in your php.ini:

```
suhosin.session.encrypt = on
suhosin.cookie.encrypt = on
session.save_handler = files
session.save_path = /tmp
```

and later write a script like:

```
$data = $argv[1];
$sessid = 'recovering';
file_put_contents("/tmp/sess_{$sessid}", $data);

session_id($sessid);
session_start();
print_r($_SESSION);
```

Which will only copy the encrypted string into a sess file and print contents (you can serialize to match the normal session behavior)

Of course if you want later that php don't encrypt through suhosin, you need to set `.encrypt = off`

Comment: Many thanks, that did the trick. One note is that I did not have the suhosin config stuff in my php.ini, as when I upgraded from 5.2 to 5.3 I told the Debian installer to not overwrite my old php.ini, at least on this particular machine. I spawned a VM clone of my pre-5.3 machine and ran the upgrade process, it replaced php.ini correctly, and the problem never occurred. Hopefully these posts are useful to some future searcher.

Comment: Thank you Daniel for this tip about session encryption. I have been struggling with session sharing between 2 servers since 2 days, and the answer is here : one had suhoshin installed, the other had not.